# Turn off AppCache Html5 when online

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem with AppCache, everything works good, until some error occured in my web, e.g some ID dont exist, so from database get null and with null i work and then on page is shown the error, ok but when i used appCache, instead of showing the error, the browser redirect me, because of fallbacks that i have in manifest. I need to show the errors in online state, not redirect. in offline state redirect. One solution, i think is that, some how i turn of appCache using in online state, and in offline state i turn on. But i dont how:(, . Or Some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved,  I separate offline and online logic, and the new logic I put to new view